# Is the expectation of the inverse of a random matrix that has diagonal expectation also diagonal?

Tags: random-variables, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, random-matrices

Suppose we have a symmetric positive definite random matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that has a diagonal matrix expectation,
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{A}) = \text{diag}(\mathbf{x}),
$$
[like e.g. the  Wishart distribution with diagonal scale matrix, $\mathcal{W}(\text{diag}(\mathbf{x}),n)$].

Is it true that
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{A}^{-k}),
$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary positive integer is also a diagonal matrix?

Edit: For the Wishart this is true. I am interested in the general statement.